# Is there a way to get around using quarter notes/rests?

Tags: piano, composition, time-signatures

I'm currently trying to compose a song in a game. Being as it is pretty much a children's game, it is rather limited in its abilities ([2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MvOAO.jpg)). I've been able to get around other limitations, such as the total lack of a bass clef, by transposing, but I'm stumped on this one. The piece ([1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ehEHN.png)) I'm trying to emulate makes use of eighth notes and rests, and the the game has no rest function. Its been years since my last music class, so I'm rusty on how everything works. Is there any way to mess with the time signature or something similar to simulate eighth notes?[image: The piece I am trying to emulate] [image: The game's composing function.]

I've already spent more time than I'd like to admit composing the other parts of the song, so it'd be disheartening to toss it all because I can't get some timing right.
Cheers

Comment: i've noticed after answering that there's a contradiction between your question header and body. the title implies that you don't have access to quarter notes, but the body says you don't have access to eighth notes (and, uh, the screenshot seems to imply that sixteenth notes are the problem). it's also very difficult to provide a definitive answer without knowing what the game is.

Comment: @Esther The game appears to be [My Singing Monsters](https://mysingingmonsters.fandom.com/wiki/My_Singing_Monsters_Wiki).

Comment: What the heck is going on in the piece you're trying to emulate? It looks polytonal with a 2-flat key signature on top and a 6-sharp key signature underneath. I can treat the piece as being in G sharp minor with a 5-sharp key signature for both staves (the second halves of Measures 12 and 14 support this), but man, reading that sheet music is not easy, and I misread the D#'s in the lower staff as B's already.

Comment: the wiki isn't great (and i'm not sure how trustworthy it is), so i won't edit my answer yet: but it seems that it does indeed support rests as i suggested, simply placing notes nonconsecutively. i'd assume that's what's happening in this [arrangement of megalovania](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wyDN1j_PQvs)

Comment: I don't understand, why are you trying to put that music into a game that looks to be for simple tunes? Why not use Musescore, or something else better suited?

Answer (score 4):

Find the smallest rhythmic value used in your piece and "scale everything up" so that smallest value in instead the smallest value supported by the game (so, if the smallest value is the sixteenth notes -- the double-stemmed notes -- in your screenshot, and the game only supports quarter-notes, then you need to quadruple the tempo and "multiply" all your rhythmic values by four; alternatively, if you were mistakenly referring to the sixteenths as eighths, then you might only need to double everything).

I find it hard to believe the game doesn't support rests in any way, can you seriously only place notes directly adjacent to each other? If the answer to that is "no, you can actually place notes non-consecutively", well then, you have rests, they're just not reflected in notation. If the answer is "yes, seriously, it's very strange", then you have two-maybe-three options: (1) just, don't use rests, let the last note you played sustain until the next one sounds; you'll get some new dissonances doing this but they'll probably resolve just fine. (2) take some creative liberties, do something new in those silences. (3) if the game supports multiple lines at once, mask the issue and simulate rests by putting the "resting" line in unison with another lines.

That said, without actually seeing the game first-hand, or having a precise and formalized description of the game's features/capabilities, there's no way of knowing whether this answer is really correct/the best way of doing things.

Answer (score 2):

1. I see the game allows the tempo to be changed, so doubling the tempo would do it.
2. Changing the time signature from 4/4 to 2/2 would also be something to try.